# Display block on two different pages

Tags: 7, views, blocks

I'd like to view my block on pages where the `content type = booking` and where the address is `node/add/booking` (basically add, edit and view nodes), how can I accomplish this? So far my code only shows on pages where `content type = booking` (i.e. view and edit nodes).

```
<?php
// Change the type to the one you want to match on
$desired_type = 'booking';
if ( arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) ) {
  $node = node_load(arg(1));
   return $node->type == $desired_type;
}

return FALSE;
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this. It uses exactly the same principles as your existing if statement.

```
// Change the type to the one you want to match on
$desired_type = 'booking';
if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
  $node = node_load(arg(1));
  return $node->type == $desired_type;
}
elseif (arg(0) == 'node' && arg(1) == 'add' && arg(2) == $desired_type) {
  return TRUE;
}
return FALSE;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
<?php
$desired_type = 'booking';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/node/add/booking') {return TRUE;} 

if ( arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) ) {
  $node = node_load(arg(1));
   return $node->type == $desired_type;
}

else {return FALSE;}
?>
```